# AWS ec2 - Windows machine launched from AMI, previous windows logins no longer work

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I understand that a Windows instance created from a custom AMI will inherit the login passwords from the instance from which I created the AMI.
This worked for me a month ago, but this time none of the 3 accounts I have work.

When I was about to Launch the AMI, the Launch button was disabled, unless I specified a Key Pair.

I’m puzzled - why did it work before, but not now?

Comment: Solved!

I set Key pair name to:
Proceed without a key pair

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

On the Launch form, I set **Key pair name** to:
**Proceed without a key pair**